# Session Show Up On Screen

Tags: php, session

I've worked on this problem for 3 days, and that the wording "SESSION_START();" shows up on my screen when I run the page.  It doesn't matter if it's HTML or PHP, I see the word session_start() in the left most part of my screen.  So how do I stop this from happening?
Thanks

Comment: People won't be able to help if all you provided is above. Key details like what is the web server are missing. If you edit the question to include more, then an answer might come.

Comment: As an HTML page, that phrase will not show up unless you have something like `<p>SESSION_START</p>` in your source file. We do need to know what web server software you're running, if other PHP files are being processed correctly, and if you have valid PHP code. Can  you run your code through [validation checker](https://phpcodechecker.com/)?